# Select query from many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql-server

I have these tables in my database

[image]

My stored procedure is

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SearchEmployee]
        @Name varchar(155),
        @Gender varchar(50),
        @MaterialStatus varchar(50),
        @DOB date,
        @Designation varchar(155),
        @Salary money
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            intEmployeeId, 
            (vchFirstName + ' ' + ISNULL(vchMiddleName,' ') + ' ' +         vchLastName) AS Name, 
            vchGender , 
            vchMaterialStatus,
            dtDOB,
            vchDesignation,
            intSalary,  
            dtmCreatedDate,
            bitActive,
            F.vchFilename As FileName ,
            F.intFileid As Fileid 
        FROM
            Employee AS E
        FULL OUTER JOIN
            EmployeeFiles AS EF ON e.intEmployeeId = EF.intEmployeeIds
        FULL OUTER JOIN
            Files AS F ON EF.intFileids = F.intFileid
        WHERE
            vchFirstName LIKE @Name OR
            vchMiddleName LIKE @Name OR
            vchLastName LIKE @Name 
    END
```

This query returns only one row

```
exec SearchEmployee @Name='m', @Gender=NULL, @MaterialStatus=NULL, 
                    @DOB='0001-01-01', @Designation=NULL, @Salary=NULL
```

I have multiple employees with a name containing the `m` character. How to get all rows from the database?

Comment: Better to SET NOCOUNT ON

Comment: FROM
            Employee AS E
         LEFT JOIN
            EmployeeFiles AS EF ON e.intEmployeeId = EF.intEmployeeIds
        LEFT JOIN
            Files AS F ON E.intFileids = F.intFileid

change full oter to left join and Files join is wrong instead of EE.intFeilds use E.intFeilds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand that you need to get all the records where name contains `M` in them. So you need to put the wild card character `%` to tell the executioner that `%` infront of `M` means any number of any characters before `M` and after the `M` means any number of any characters after the `M`. [Read more about it here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

So for that you need to alter your `like` condition

```
    vchFirstName like '%'+@Name+'%' OR
    vchMiddleName like '%'+@Name+'%' OR
    vchLastName like '%'+@Name+'%'
```